# RestKit custom RKValueTransformer not being run for NSDate property

Tags: ios, restkit

I would like to run a custom `RKValueTransformer` on an `NSDate` property when creating a *specific request*. I'm happy (and would prefer to) use the default in all other scenarios. My understanding is that I can set up the mapping, specify a value transformer and it'll use that, only falling back to the defaults if no value transformer is set. I'm running RestKit 0.23.3.

I have the following mapping set up for my request (I've obviously trimmed a bunch from this):

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * dueDate;

...

+(RKEntityMapping *) createRequestMapping
{
    static RKEntityMapping* map = nil;
    if (map == nil)
    {
        map = (RKEntityMapping *)[RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
        [map addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:...];

        RKValueTransformer *dueDateValueTransformer = [RKBlockValueTransformer valueTransformerWithValidationBlock:^BOOL(__unsafe_unretained Class inputValueClass, __unsafe_unretained Class outputValueClass) {
            return [inputValueClass isSubclassOfClass:[NSDate class]];
        } transformationBlock:^BOOL(id inputValue, __autoreleasing id *outputValue, __unsafe_unretained Class outputClass, NSError *__autoreleasing *error) {
            *outputValue = [[self dueDateRequestFormatter] stringFromDate:inputValue];
            return YES;
        }];
        RKAttributeMapping *dueDateMapping = [RKAttributeMapping attributeMappingFromKeyPath:@"dueDate" toKeyPath:@"due_date"];
        dueDateMapping.valueTransformer = dueDateValueTransformer;
        [map addPropertyMapping:dueDateMapping];
    }
    return map;
}
```

When my test for this runs, I can see that the mapping is used (since the target key path "due_date" exists in the dictionary), but the value transformer is not - rather, it appears the default `NSDate` transformer is used:

```
    XCTAssertEqualObjects(@"2014-05-01", [item objectForKey:@"due_date"]);
```

> -[RestKitCreateMappingTests testCreateSequenceMappings] failed: ((@"2014-05-01") equal to ([item objectForKey:@"due_date"])) failed: ("2014-05-01") is not equal to ("2014-05-01 00:00:00 +0000")

I've set breakpoints in both the validation and transformation blocks, and neither is hit.

Why is RestKit not using my value transformer?

Comment: Show how you're using the mapping

Comment: Thanks Wain, I've added the relevant parts of my test.

Comment: And the model data type for the attribute is date, not string? I can't see an obvious issue, probably best to have a quick debug of the test class to check that it gets to the transformation stage and what it does (also look for the RestKit unit test of the value transformer).

Comment: Yeah, definitely NSDate, I added the property up top - its date in the model file too. Okay, I'll do some digging. Appreciate your looking!

Comment: Well that [wasn't in the docs](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping). I'd still be stuck on this if RestKit wasn't open source. Rolled the question back, since the extra info was pretty irrelevant. Edit: Turns out [it _is_ in _these_ docs](https://github.com/RestKit/RKValueTransformers/blob/50236b057fbf3bd1d1e508cd876a19c5a7d6b5a3/README.md).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to specify the `propertyValueClass` so that RestKit knew what type of target property to map to:

```
RKAttributeMapping *dueDateMapping = [RKAttributeMapping attributeMappingFromKeyPath:@"dueDate" toKeyPath:@"due_date"];
dueDateMapping.valueTransformer = dueDateValueTransformer;
dueDateMapping.propertyValueClass = [NSString class];
[map addPropertyMapping:dueDateMapping];
```

Without this, the [following check failed](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/07dd10215f7991a5c0f4244289d6fbb3521c5a27/Code/ObjectMapping/RKMappingOperation.m#L442) in the mapping operation, and it never got a chance to use the custom value transformer, rather it just outputs the input value:

```
Class transformedValueClass = propertyMapping.propertyValueClass ?: [self.objectMapping classForKeyPath:propertyMapping.destinationKeyPath];
if (! transformedValueClass) {
    *outputValue = inputValue;
    return YES;
}
BOOL success = [propertyMapping.valueTransformer transformValue:inputValue toValue:outputValue ofClass:transformedValueClass error:error];
return success;
```

Comment: This was it!  they are missing this on the Documentation, thanks for documenting it!